# Python fileinput and sorted

Tags: python, file-io, sorting

Hello I am trying to overwrite a file via the use of fileinput, however, before i overwrite the file i need to sort the file first as i am doing some process after sorting- which tells the script which line is applicable will be used to overwrite the existing file.

I cannot output into a temporary file and am restricted to overwriting

The code below does not work

```
for line in fileinput.input(sorted(open(Filename)), inplace = True):
~process~
print line
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You might try giving the `fileinput` docs a careful read...

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
for line in sorted(file.readlines(open('temp/tab1'))):
    ~process~
    print line
```